# Java append an image into JTextArea

Tags: java, netbeans, append, insert-image

TLDR: Insert an image in a JTextArea that will be generated afterwards.

I'm new on using Java, doing my first real project. I am trying to make an application that creates documents based on input variables that represent the keywords in a "template". Basically I created on the left of the GUI a few JTextFields that I print out in the JTextArea with append and then I generate the document.

What I am trying to do atm is to insert an image in that append, image that will be in the generated document.

The code so far for what I specified below.

JTextArea append, where I would like to insert the image:

```
private void ADDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    txtReceipt.append(
        "\t\t CONTRACT DETAILS \n\n" +
        "LEASE NUMBER:\t\t\t" + txtContract.getText() +
        "insert text template here"
    );
}
```

Between the lines of text I would like to add the image. The txtContract variable is a JTextField and the txtReceipt is the JTextArea.

Generate button:

```
private void GENERATEActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        txtReceipt.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GeneratorContracte.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I found another threads on this subject but they were adding images in an already created document or generating a doc. The problem is that I didn't figure out what line of the codes does print the image. Also, I don't know if JTextArea supports images.

I am using NetBeans if that matters.
Sorry for the wall of text, but I tried to specify the issue without posting the whole code. I believe this way makes it easier to find a solution.

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: JTextArea is purely for text. You may want to look at JTextPane

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried to add a JTextPane for test and used panename.insertIcon ( new ImageIcon ( "/path/to/image.png" ) ); but it didn't work. I'm not sure why

Comment: I meant that you should use a JTextPane for inserting images, not to try to insert a JTextPane into a JTextArea

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes. I created a JTextPane (separated from the JTextArea) and used the line "panename.insertIcon ( new ImageIcon ( "/path/to/image.png" ) );" . Where panename is the name of the var of the JTextPane. From what I found online that's the line that should add the image. I also found a way to do it with html, but that doesn't find with the rest of the code I have

Comment: I can't speak to the rest of your code, as you haven't posted it or commented extensively about it. Your original question was "How do I append an image into a JTextArea?" You have learned (a) that is isn't supported through JTextArea, and (b) How to do it in JTextpane. In my opinion, you should post the testing you did that you mentioned in your last comment, mark this question answered (with you answer), then try moving your solution to use JTextPane instead of JTextArea and post another question here if you have another problem